# C# XML attribute being created improperly

Tags: c#, xml

I'm creating a node programmatically, however one of the attributes comes out differently than what I specified in the code:

```
                XmlNode xResource = docXMLFile.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "resource", docXMLFile.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
                XmlAttribute xRefIdentifier = docXMLFile.CreateAttribute("identifier");
                XmlAttribute xRefADLCP = docXMLFile.CreateAttribute("adlcp:scormtype");
                XmlAttribute xRefHREF = docXMLFile.CreateAttribute("href");
                XmlAttribute xRefType = docXMLFile.CreateAttribute("type");
                xRefIdentifier.Value = "RES-" + strRes;
                xRefADLCP.Value = "sco";
                xRefHREF.Value = dataRow["launch_url"].ToString().ToLower();
                xRefType.Value = "webcontent";

                xResource.Attributes.Append(xRefIdentifier);
                xResource.Attributes.Append(xRefADLCP);
                xResource.Attributes.Append(xRefHREF);
                xResource.Attributes.Append(xRefType);
```

This ends up creating a line like the following.  Note that 'adlcp:scormtype' has morphed into 'scormtype' which is not what I specified.  Any ideas how to get it to show what I put in the CreateAttribute?

```
 <resource identifier="RES-CDA68F64B849460B93BF2840A9487358" scormtype="sco" href="start.html" type="webcontent" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably expected behavior of this override [CreateAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createattribute.aspx) combined with saving the document:

> The NamespaceURI remains empty unless the prefix is a recognized built-in prefix such as xmlns. In this case NamespaceURI has a value of http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/.

Use another override [XmlDocument.CreateAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs2zzesf.aspx) to specify namespace and prefix:

```
XmlAttribute xRefADLCP = docXMLFile.CreateAttribute(
     "adlcp","scormtype", "correct-namespace-here");
```

Comment: I tried adding this:   XmlAttribute xRefADLCP = docXMLFile.CreateAttribute("adlcp", "scormtype", docXMLFile.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);      the problem is that it then added another attribute for xmlns:adlcp="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2".  Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Comment: You are redefining the namespace. From other comment on the root - `xmlns:adlcp="adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2";`, from this - `xmlns:adlcp="imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2" `. Up to you to decide what you want, if namespaces the same I believe there will be no duplicated xmlns attribute on the child element.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [Prefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute.prefix) for the attribute directly, instead of trying to create the attribute inline with the prefix.

```
XmlAttribute xRefADLCP = docXMLFile.CreateAttribute("scormtype");
// ...
xRefADLCP.Prefix = "adlcp";
xRefADLCP.Value = "sco";
```

Comment: for some reason, that gives the same result, the prefix doesn't appear.  I have no idea why.  I had tried this before and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @user1366062 Do you have the namespace defined in your XML document?  It must exist (and in the proper scope)  Make sure to include the xmlns definition appropriately somewhere

Comment: the top of the document includes the following, which I imagine should cover it.  <manifest identifier="Manifest1" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2" xmlns:imsmd="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_rootv1p2p1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2 imscp_rootv1p1p2.xsd http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsmd_rootv1p2p1 imsmd_rootv1p2p1.xsd http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_rootv1p2 adlcp_rootv1p2.xsd">